# Find $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \left[\left((\frac {x+1}{x-1})^x - e^2\right)x^2\right ]$

Tags: limits

Replacing $x\to \frac 1t$

$$L=\lim\limits_{t\to 0} \frac{\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)^{1/t}-e^2}{t^2}$$

Clearly L is of $\frac 00$ form. However I am not able to find any standard limit embedded within and L’Hospital doesn’t seem very useful. Can I get a hint to proceed further?

Comment: Work the first piece taking logarithms and Taylor series

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis in the title.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\frac{\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)^{1/t}-e^2}{t^2}=  \frac{e^2}{t^2}\cdot\left(e^{\frac{1}{t}\ln \frac{1+t}{1-t} -2}-1 \right) \sim \\
=\frac{e^2}{t^2} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{t}\ln \frac{1+t}{1-t} -2\right)=\frac{e^2}{t^2} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{t}\ln\left(1+ \frac{2t}{1-t}\right) -2\right)=\\
=\frac{e^2}{t^3} \cdot \left(-2t+ \frac{2t}{1-t} - \left(\frac{2t}{1-t}\right)^2\frac{1}{2} +\left(\frac{2t}{1-t}\right)^3\frac{1}{3}-\cdots\right)$$
noting $-2t+ \frac{2t}{1-t} =\frac{2t^2}{1-t} $, you can join it to 3'd member of series. Hope this helps.